# UIPrintPageRenderer rendered to PDF (font rendering)

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, pdf, fonts

I'm trying to render a HTML page to PDF. But everytime I do this, and a font is not installed I just get random characters. -> http://cl.ly/WYCN . Also, When using a font like Helvetica a web preview via Gmail still shows these characters. I'd like to use a custom TTF font too.

What I've tried:

1. Rendering the HTML with Helvetica -> Seems to work on all OS's but Web Preview.
2. Rendering the HTML with Source Sans Pro (open source font, .ttf) -> Does only work on systems having Source Sans Pro installed. I did include the TTF in the bundle, added it to "Fonts required by application" and it's showing up with `[UIFont familyNames]`.
3. Adding `@font-face` in HTML for using Source Sans Pro

Is there any chance I can embed a font into a PDF using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [iOS Quartz embed font in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600085/ios-quartz-embed-font-in-pdf).
It turns out that you can only embed TTF fonts, but if you follow the same procedure as he does, it should automatically be embedded. In this thread: [IOS embed font in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980388/ios-embed-font-in-pdf) they end up with the same solution. You may also want to read this: [Embed custom font in a PDF generated from iPad Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364359/embed-custom-font-in-a-pdf-generated-from-ipad-application?lq=1) because some font foundries disable embedding of their fonts (of course this does not apply to open source fonts but you may want to read it anyway).